# Place empty gap inside text paragraph

Tags: css

I have a text paragraph with long text:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum ... </p>
```

I have set a background image for this paragraph on the top right corner. I want to force this text to do not cover this background but float it. So I need a "partial" `padding-right` with limited height (background image's height).

Is it possible to do with just CSS ?

Comment: Have you condidered putting the background image to a outer container div, then putting the <p> inside this outer container (div). Alternatively, put the image inside the <p> and float right with a left padding..

Comment: No - I cannot modify DOM structure - just use CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a floating pseudo element.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/4nssk/)

```
p {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
p:before {
    content: "";
    float: right;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I've updated it for the right fiddle. Couldn't understand your sentence though.